# UITableView Animation when entering Editmode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uianimation

Maybe I´m just stupid but I cant understand why this isnt working. 
I want to achieve a little animation when I'm entering editing mode within a UITableView.

```
 [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];   
 [myTable setEditing:NO animated:YES];
 [myTable reloadData];
 [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
 [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
```

Shouldnt this animated:YES suppose to animated this entering of the editmode?

Regards.
- f0rz

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution,  I was reloading the tableview .  This was making the animation to stop.
Removed [myTable reloadData] and it worked again!